# Merging multiple columns in Oracle based on row value

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I've looked through many merging columns question and haven't been able to find one that addresses my rather specific issue. I'm working on a project for school, and I have most of it done, but I'm stuck on one tiny part of this question.

Basically, I run the DESCRIBE command on a table I created and get this result:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ------------
COURSEID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7)
COURSE_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35)
STUDENT_COUNT                                      NUMBER(5)
```

What I need to do is recreate this result using the USER_TAB_COLS data dictionary. Here's what I have so far and it's result:

```
select column_name "Name",
       replace(replace(nullable, 'N', 'NOT NULL'), 'Y') "Null?",
       (data_type || '(' || data_length || ')') "Type"
  from user_tab_cols
 where column_name = 'COURSEID'
    or column_name = 'COURSE_NAME'
    or column_name = 'STUDENT_COUNT';


Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ------------
COURSEID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7)
COURSE_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35)
STUDENT_COUNT                                      NUMBER(22)
```

My issue is with the STUDENT_COUNT row. The value for Type is wrong. The other two rows need to combine the DATA_TYPE and DATA_LENGTH columns to get the correct output, but STUDENT_COUNT needs to combine DATA_TYPE and DATA_PRECISION to get the correct output. How do I go about combining different columns into one, depending on the row? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Decode() or a case would help

Comment: Thanks. Case worked perfectly for what I need. But I've never heard of Decode(). How does it work exactly?

Comment: Decode(data_type,'NUMBER',data_precision,data_length) thats it!!

Comment: Nice and simple. I like it! I'll definitely have to remember that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify it to use a CASE statement like below:

```
select column_name "Name",
       replace(replace(nullable, 'N', 'NOT NULL'), 'Y') "Null?",
       (data_type || '(' || case
         when data_type = 'NUMBER' then
          data_precision
         else
          data_length
       end || ')') "Type"
  from user_tab_cols
 where column_name = 'COURSEID'
    or column_name = 'COURSE_NAME'
    or column_name = 'STUDENT_COUNT';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Using a case never even crossed my mind. Works perfectly now. Thank you for the help.